# Mail being sent to gmail, yahoo, but not to personal mail servers

Tags: php, email

I am facing a weird problem. When I send out mails using PHP's mail() function, the mail is being sent perfectly to gmail and yahoo(though it was marked as spam in yahoo), but the mail is not received by my company's email address.

I don't have direct access to the server, only ftp to the public_html folder, hence I can't check the logs.....

Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT:

```
$mailfrom="website@mysite.com";
                            $mailto=$buyerrow['email'];
                            $subject="Test Details";
                            $body='Hi '.$buyerrow['name'].'!<br>Test Details below:<br><br><br><br><br>Thanks<br>Web Team';
                            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";    
                            $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; carset=iso-8859-1;\r\n";   
                            $headers.= "From: ADMIN <".$mailfrom.">\r\n";
                            @mail($mailto,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f website@mysite.com");
```

As for the spam folders at my company's server, I am quite sure it didn't end up there either....

Is it possible that there is some server setting which allows php to send mail to only particular server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many company mailservers are set up to outright reject some types of spam immediately during the SMTP session. If that happens, it will never make it to your companies spam folder. You should check with your company system administrator.

If you're in doubt, you can always use an application like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture and analyse the actual SMTP traffic.

Comment: But it the same mail with same headers and content is being sent to gmail and yahoo..... if it was rejected as spam then how can those two receive them?

Comment: Every mailserver can have different rules for accepting or rejecting e-mail. Your company can reject e-mail that Yahoo and GMail accept. Ask your system administrator or use Wireshark to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on the Spam folder ? also check whether you have set HEADERS properly with from name etc.,

Comment: I added the code above with minor edits, please see if you spot any coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your company's server mail server.

Make sure to test it [send email from yahoo to your company email address] and double check the mx records.